# How can a compare a cell with the previous visible cell above

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to shade every other group of visiable cells.

Each row of my data contains information on a given Order and there can be multiple rows for each order, e.g. Order 1 many have 3 rows while order 2 may have 1 row, etc. The data is sorted by Order Number so all rows for a given order are contiguous.

I have shaded each group vis a helper column (AS) containing the following formula: `=IF(ROW()=2,TRUE,IF(A2=A1,AS1,NOT(AS1)))`
which results in every other Order group being either TRUE or False. Then I use conditional formatting to shade every "TRUE" row.

This works until I begin filtering my data and then I can end up with either two shaded or to unshaded groups next to each other.

I think what I'm looking for is a VBA function that will compare a cell with previous VISIBLE cell and will return TRUE or FALSE if the match or not.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I can almost guarantee you there's a better way to do what you're trying. I'd consider using a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code that shades every other row

```
Sub ShadeThem()

    Dim okShade As Boolean
    
    Dim r As Range
        For Each r In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If okShade Then
                r.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                okShade = False
            Else
                okShade = True
            End If
        Next
        
End Sub
```

I assumed your filtered data affect column A from row 1 downwards
Did they not, just change `"A1"` and `Cells(Rows.Count, "A")` to affect the needed column

In order to have it run at every new filtering, you could:

- add a helper cell which counts the number of visible rows
  =SUBTOTAL(103;A1:A1000)
  this will trigger the `Worksheet_Calculate` event at every filtering
- add the `Worksheet_Calculate` event hander in the relevant sheet code pane

  ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

       ShadeThem

   End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, there's almost surely a better way to do what you're trying as a whole with your spreadsheet (a table!).  However, if you really wanted a VBA custom formula to test if a cell is hidden or not you could use this...

```
Function isHiddenRow(aRange As Range) As Boolean

    isHiddenRow = aRange.EntireRow.Hidden

End Function
```

There's some possibilities this formula assumes:

- Only one cell.
- Filtering impact of recalculations.